# Can't get passed error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol, even if I seem to have included what is needed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to create a game with c++ and SMFL 2.0 and i cant get pass this error and it's driving me crazy. I have been reading around the internet and it seems like it can be caused because of forgotten includes, but I still cant see where I have gone wrong. I have included the SMFL 2.0 library in the project properties section under c++ -> general -> additional include directories and under linker -> general -> additional library directories.

I'm completely blank and this is the error message i get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Pang, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Game.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  Pang.cpp
1>Game.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class PlayerPaddle Game::_player1" (?_player1@Game@@0VPlayerPaddle@@A)
1>C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\C++\Projects\Pang\Debug\Pang.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Microsoft Visual C++ doesnt show any syntax grammar errors with red underline when im looking around the code so it looks like the syntax is ok. Here are the relevant lines of code:

I have most of my general includes here:

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
```

VisibleGameObject.h

```
#pragma once

class VisibleGameObject {

    public:
        VisibleGameObject();
        virtual ~VisibleGameObject();

        virtual void Load(std::string filename);
        virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);

        virtual void SetPosition(float x, float y);

    private:
        sf::Sprite  _sprite;
        sf::Texture _image;
        std::string _filename;
        bool _isLoaded;

};
```

VisibleGameObject.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VisibleGameObject.h"

VisibleGameObject::VisibleGameObject() {
    _isLoaded = false;
}
VisibleGameObject::~VisibleGameObject() {
}
void VisibleGameObject::Load(std::string filename) {

    if (_image.loadFromFile(filename) == false) {
        _filename = "";
        _isLoaded = false;
    }
    else {
        _filename = filename;
        _sprite.setTexture(_image);
    }
}

void VisibleGameObject::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &renderWindow) {

    if (_isLoaded) {
        renderWindow.draw(_sprite);
    }
}

void VisibleGameObject::SetPosition(float x, float y) {

    if (_isLoaded) {
        _sprite.setPosition(x,y);
    }

}
```

This class helps me use the SMFL library to draw images on the rendered window.

PlayerPaddle.h

```
#pragma once
#include "VisibleGameObject.h"

class PlayerPaddle : public VisibleGameObject {

    public:
        PlayerPaddle();
        ~PlayerPaddle();
};
```

PlayerPaddle.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VisibleGameObject.h"
#include "PlayerPaddle.h"

PlayerPaddle::PlayerPaddle() {
}
PlayerPaddle::~PlayerPaddle() {
}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once
#include "PlayerPaddle.h"

class Game {

public:
    static void Start();

private:
    static bool IsExiting();
    static void GameLoop();

    static void ShowSplashScreen();
    static void ShowMenu();

    enum GameState { Uninitialized, ShowingSplash, Paused, ShowingMenu, Playing, Exiting };

    static GameState _gameState;
    static sf::RenderWindow _mainWindow;
    static PlayerPaddle _player1;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "SplashScreen.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"


void Game::Start(void) {

    if(_gameState != Uninitialized) {
        return;
    }

    _mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(1024,768,32),"Pang!");

    //_player1.Load("images/paddle.png");
    //_player1.SetPosition((1024/2)-45, 700);

    _gameState = Game::ShowingSplash;

    while(!IsExiting()) {
        GameLoop();
    }

    _mainWindow.close();
}

bool Game::IsExiting() {

    if(_gameState == Game::Exiting) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void Game::GameLoop() {

    switch(_gameState) {

        case Game::ShowingMenu: {
            ShowMenu();
            break;
        }
        case Game::ShowingSplash: {
            ShowSplashScreen();
            break;
        }
        case Game::Playing: {
            sf::Event currentEvent;
            while (_mainWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent)) {
                _mainWindow.clear(sf::Color(0,0,0));
                //_player1.Draw(_mainWindow);
                _mainWindow.display();

                if (currentEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                    _gameState = Game::Exiting;
                }

                if (currentEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                    return;

                    if(currentEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                        ShowMenu();
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::ShowSplashScreen() {
    SplashScreen splashScreen;
    splashScreen.Show(_mainWindow);
    _gameState = Game::ShowingMenu;
}

void Game::ShowMenu() {
    MainMenu mainMenu;
    MainMenu::MenuResult result = mainMenu.Show(_mainWindow);
    switch(result) {
        case MainMenu::Exit: {
            _gameState = Game::Exiting;
            break;
        }
        case MainMenu::Play: {
            _gameState = Game::Playing;
            break;
        }
    }
}

Game::GameState Game::_gameState = Uninitialized;
sf::RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow;
```

This code compiles and runs ONLY when those 3 lines of codes starting with _player1 in Game.cpp are commented out. When not commented out i get this LNK2001 error and I just cant get passed this and it is quite frustrating.

Would be nice if someone had input on what could be wrong here.

Best of regards,
Alexander

Comment: You've declared your `class Game` static class variables within the class definition, but where did you *define* them? I don't see them anywhere in your source lists. Two of them are there, but the third (the one missing in the link) is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your game.cpp misses a definition of Game::_player1:

```
PlayerPaddle Game::_player1;
```

Comment: When I write that before _player1.Load("images/paddle.png"); i get red underline syntax error below _player in PlayerPaddle Game::_player1;

Comment: Copy it to the end of your game.cpp where you defined the 2 other static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You properly define the static member variables `_gameState` and `_mainWindow`, but not `_player1`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, how do you mean i should define it?

Comment: @Alexander Last in the file `Game.cpp` you _define_ the static member variables `_gameState` and `_mainWindow`. You need to do the same for `_player1`.

Comment: oh ofc, at the bottom.. thanks! i forgot i defined them there

Answer (score 0):

1) Try inheriting publicily PlayerPaddle class to Game class.It works.
Example

> **class Game:public PlayerPaddle**

2) or you can use composition.Use a pointer or static pointer to PlayerPaddle in Game.
Use

> static **PlayerPaddle*** _player1;

It should work.